Fast pairwise longest common substring from start
Suppose there are many binary strings
x <- c("0100100010101010", "0100110010101010","0111001000","010111")


I am looking for a fast method in R to output a matrix containing the pairwise (excluding self-matches) longest common substring from the start. For example, a solution could look like this
> mySolution(x)
    [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] ""       "01001"   "01"     "010"
[2,] "01001"  ""        "01"     "010"
[3,] "01"     "01"      ""       "01"
[4,] "010"    "010"     "01"     ""

E.g., the matrix at position [1,2] is the longest common substring from the start of x[1] and x[2]. Note that the resulting matrix is symmetric. So, we only need to compute one half of it.
I know that could work with functions like substr,sub,grepl, but since I have many strings, I am looking for a very efficient solution that requires little computation time. Maybe it is an option to convert to binary numbers to improve performance?

Relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring

How fast is "fast"? Please edit the question to specify what is an acceptable solution in terms of objective metrics.

Update
An even faster solution for large vectors of binary strings. The function flcs below is able to perform the desired operation on 10k binary character strings in about 1 second.
The idea is that if two binary strings are seen as big-endian representations of integer values, then the absolute value of the difference of the two values will have a number of leading zeros equal to their longest common series of bits from the beginning.
Demonstrating:
as.integer(intToBits(29))
#>  [1] 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
as.integer(intToBits(13))
#>  [1] 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
as.integer(intToBits(abs(29 - 13)))
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

The big-endian binary representation of 16 has 4 leading zeros, which is the number of same leading bits between 29 and 13 (see https://oeis.org/A007814).
One option is to convert each string to integer, calculate all pairwise distances, then determine the number of leading zeros. However, since the length of the strings can exceed 31, this would require working with arbitrarily large integers using, e.g., gmp::bigz, which is relatively slow.
The algorithm used by flcs first pre-computes the number of leading zeros for all binary strings of length d. Then the strings are broken into substrings of length d and sequentially checked via differencing and indexing until there is no longer a complete match. (The algorithm is similar to the previous answer, but it processes d characters at once.) All computations are performed on base R integer values, so the algorithm is very fast.
system.time({
  d <- 12L
  nn <- integer(2^d)
  d2 <- 2^(0:d)
  nn[sequence(d2[(d - 1):1], d2[2:d] + 1, d2[3:(d + 1)])] <-
    rep.int(1:(d - 1), d2[(d - 1):1])
  nn[1] <- d
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0

flcs returns the endpoint of the pairwise common substring, which can be used to fill the bottom triangle of the desired matrix.
library(data.table) # for `tstrsplit`
library(stringi) # for `stri_reverse`

flcs <- function(x) {
  nx <- length(x)
  nx1 <- nx - 1L
  j2 <- sequence(nx1:1, 2:nx)
  y <- tstrsplit(gsub(sprintf("(.{%d})", d), "\\1 ", x), " ")
  y[[1]] <- strtoi(stri_reverse(y[[1]]), base = 2)
  n <- nn[abs(rep.int(y[[1]][-nx], nx1:1) - y[[1]][j2]) + 1L]
  idx <- which(n == d)

  if (length(idx)) {
    j1 <- rep.int(1:nx1, nx1:1)

    for (k in (1:length(y))[-1]) {
      y[[k]] <- strtoi(stri_reverse(y[[k]]), base = 2)
      j3 <- abs(y[[k]][j1[idx]] - y[[k]][j2[idx]])
      idx <- idx[b <- !is.na(j3)]
      nplus <- nn[j3[b] + 1L]
      n[idx] <- n[idx] + nplus
      idx <- idx[nplus == d]
      if (!length(idx)) break
    }
  }

  lens <- nchar(x)
  pmin(n, rep.int(lens[-nx], nx1:1), lens[j2])
}

Demonstrating:
x <- c("0100100010101010", "0100110010101010","0111001000","010111")
flcs(x)
#> [1] 5 2 3 2 3 2

A function to build the final matrix from the output of flcs:
buildmat <- function(x, n, symmetric = FALSE, fill = "") {
  nx <- length(x)
  nx1 <- nx - 1L
  z <- matrix(fill, nx, nx)
  if (symmetric) {
    z[sequence(nx1:1, seq(2, nx^2, nx + 1))] <-
      z[sequence(nx1:1, seq(nx + 1, nx^2, nx + 1), nx)] <-
      substr(x[rep.int(1:nx1, nx1:1)], 1, n)
  } else {
    z[sequence(nx1:1, seq(2, nx^2, nx + 1))] <-
      substr(x[rep.int(1:nx1, nx1:1)], 1, n)
  }
  
  z
}

buildmat(x, flcs(x), TRUE)
#>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3] [,4] 
#> [1,] ""      "01001" "01" "010"
#> [2,] "01001" ""      "01" "010"
#> [3,] "01"    "01"    ""   "01" 
#> [4,] "010"   "010"   "01" ""

Compare to three other approaches. The first compares each string to each other string in parallel. The other two are from the answers given by @ThomasIsCoding and @AndreWildberg.
library(parallel)

f <- function(x, y) {
  n <- min(length(x[[1]]), length(x[[2]]))
  out <- which.max(x[[1]][1:n] != x[[2]][1:n])
  if (out == 1L && x[[1]][1] == x[[2]][1]) n + 1L else out
}

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) # 15 cores
clusterExport(cl, c("f"), environment(f))

flcsPar <- function(x) {
  unlist(parLapply(cl, combn(lapply(x, utf8ToInt), 2, NULL, FALSE), f)) - 1L
}

getPsub <- function(dat){ # from @AndreWildberg
  len <- seq_along(dat)
  mlen <- max(len)
  mat <- matrix(NA, mlen, mlen)
  d <- do.call(rbind, tstrsplit(dat, ""))
  mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- apply(combn(len, 2), 2, \(x){
    res <- d[,x[1]] == d[,x[2]]
    paste(d[rleid(res) == 1 & res, x[1]], collapse="")})
  mat
}

helper <- function(a, b) { # from @ThomasIsCoding
  l <- min(nchar(a), nchar(b))
  aa <- substr(a, 1, l)
  bb <- substr(b, 1, l)
  vaa <- utf8ToInt(aa)
  vbb <- utf8ToInt(bb)
  if (aa == bb) {
    aa
  } else {
    k <- which.max(vaa != vbb) - 1
    ifelse(k > 0, intToUtf8(vaa[1:k]), "")
  }
}

f2 <- function(x) { # from @ThomasIsCoding
  res <- matrix(rep(NA, length(x)^2), length(x))
  v <- combn(x, 2, \(p) helper(p[1], p[2]))
  res[lower.tri(res)] <- v
  res
}

The functions by @ThomasIsCoding and @AndreWildberg have been modified slightly to give identical outputs:
buildmat(x, flcsPar(x), FALSE, NA)
#>      [,1]    [,2]  [,3] [,4]
#> [1,] NA      NA    NA   NA  
#> [2,] "01001" NA    NA   NA  
#> [3,] "01"    "01"  NA   NA  
#> [4,] "010"   "010" "01" NA
getPsub(x)
#>      [,1]    [,2]  [,3] [,4]
#> [1,] NA      NA    NA   NA  
#> [2,] "01001" NA    NA   NA  
#> [3,] "01"    "01"  NA   NA  
#> [4,] "010"   "010" "01" NA
f2(x)
#>      [,1]    [,2]  [,3] [,4]
#> [1,] NA      NA    NA   NA  
#> [2,] "01001" NA    NA   NA  
#> [3,] "01"    "01"  NA   NA  
#> [4,] "010"   "010" "01" NA

Time the four solutions with a character vector of length 10k, with the string lengths varying from 10 to 64.
x <- vapply(1:1e4, \(.) intToUtf8(sample(48:49, sample(10:64, 1), 1)), "")
system.time(m1 <- buildmat(x, flcsPar(x), FALSE, NA))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   66.61   60.50  363.88
stopCluster(cl)
system.time(m2 <- buildmat(x, flcs(x), FALSE, NA))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    3.47    1.25    4.69
identical(m1, m2)
#> [1] TRUE
system.time(m2 <- getPsub(x))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  596.86   59.57  661.10
identical(m1, m2)
#> [1] TRUE
system.time(m2 <- f2(x))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  378.62    5.30  383.78
identical(m1, m2)
#> [1] TRUE

If only the pairwise lengths are needed, there is no need for buildmat:
system.time(flcs(x))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.84    0.31    1.16

flcs performed nearly 50 million comparisons in about 1 second.

Original Answer
A fast solution for large vectors of binary strings. The function flcs below is able to perform the desired operation on 10k binary character strings in about 13 seconds.
The idea is to sequentially check the kth character of each string and put each string into a 0 bin or a 1 bin. The longest common substring between i and j terminates at or before k if i and j are in different bins.
flcs returns the endpoint of the pairwise common substring, which can be used to fill the bottom triangle of the desired matrix.
library(data.table)

flcs <- function(x) {
  y <- lapply(x, \(x) utf8ToInt(x) == 49L)
  nx <- length(x)
  nx1 <- nx - 1L
  lens <- lengths(y)
  dt <- data.table(
    v = unlist(y),
    i = sequence(lens),
    j1 = rep.int(1:nx, lens)
  )[,j2 := (j1 - 1L)*nx]
  # `n` is a vector containing the earliest mismatch between pairs
  n <- pmin(lens[rep.int(1:nx1, nx1:1)], lens[sequence(nx1:1, 2:nx)])
  b <- logical(length(n))
  # create a vector `idx` to map to the indices of `n`
  idx <- integer(nx^2)
  idx[sequence(nx1:1, seq(2, nx^2, nx + 1))] <-
    idx[sequence(nx1:1, seq(nx + 1, nx^2, nx + 1), nx)] <- 1:length(n)
  
  for (k in 1:-sort.int(-lens, 2)[2]) {
    nstop <- idx[dt[i == k, outer(j2[v], j1[!v], "+")]]
    nstop <- nstop[!b[nstop]]
    b[nstop] <- TRUE
    n[nstop] <- k - 1L
    if (all(b)) break
  }
  
  n
}

Demonstrating:
x <- c("0100100010101010", "0100110010101010","0111001000","010111")
flcs(x)
#> [1] 5 2 3 2 3 2

A function to build the final matrix from the output of flcs:
buildmat <- function(x, n, symmetric = FALSE) {
  nx <- length(x)
  nx1 <- nx - 1L
  z <- matrix("", nx, nx)
  if (symmetric) {
    z[sequence(nx1:1, seq(2, nx^2, nx + 1))] <-
      z[sequence(nx1:1, seq(nx + 1, nx^2, nx + 1), nx)] <-
      substr(x[rep.int(1:nx1, nx1:1)], 1, n)
  } else {
    z[sequence(nx1:1, seq(2, nx^2, nx + 1))] <-
      substr(x[rep.int(1:nx1, nx1:1)], 1, n)
  }
  
  z
}

buildmat(x, flcs(x), TRUE)
#>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3] [,4] 
#> [1,] ""      "01001" "01" "010"
#> [2,] "01001" ""      "01" "010"
#> [3,] "01"    "01"    ""   "01" 
#> [4,] "010"   "010"   "01" ""

Compare to a solution that compares each string to each other string in parallel.
library(parallel)

f <- function(x) {
  n <- min(length(x[[1]]), length(x[[2]]))
  out <- which.max(x[[1]][1:n] != x[[2]][1:n])
  if (out == 1L && x[[1]][1] == x[[2]][1]) n + 1L else out
}

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) # 15 cores
clusterExport(cl, c("f"), environment(f))

flcsPar <- function(x) {
  unlist(parLapply(cl, combn(lapply(x, utf8ToInt), 2, NULL, FALSE), f)) - 1L
}

buildmat(x, flcsPar(x), TRUE)
#>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3] [,4] 
#> [1,] ""      "01001" "01" "010"
#> [2,] "01001" ""      "01" "010"
#> [3,] "01"    "01"    ""   "01" 
#> [4,] "010"   "010"   "01" ""

Time the two functions on a vector of 10k binary strings.
x <- vapply(1:1e4, \(.) intToUtf8(sample(48:49, sample(10:20, 1), 1)), "")
system.time(n1 <- flcs(x))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    9.84    3.41   13.26
system.time(n2 <- flcsPar(x))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   69.31   54.53  242.07
identical(n1, n2)
#> [1] TRUE

flcs performed nearly 50 million comparisons in about 13 seconds.

This is indeed a very fast solution, and faster than all others posted.

Glad it's working for you. Just curious--how large are your character vectors, and about how long are the strings in them?

Most binary strings are shorter than 64 symbols. I have dozens of datasets with different numbers of strings. The smallest has only a few hundred. The largest consists of roughly two hundred million strings.

See the updated answer. It runs an order of magnitude faster than the previous answer and roughly two orders of magnitude faster than the other answers.

Maybe not that performant but should work as expected if you have a helper function to find the longest common substring from the start
helper <- function(a, b) {
    l <- min(nchar(a), nchar(b))
    aa <- substr(a, 1, l)
    bb <- substr(b, 1, l)
    vaa <- utf8ToInt(aa)
    vbb <- utf8ToInt(bb)
    if (aa == bb) {
        aa
    } else {
        k <- which.max(vaa != vbb) - 1
        ifelse(k > 0, intToUtf8(vaa[1:k]), "")
    }
}

and on top of it you can define custom functions f1() or f2(), e.g.,
f1 <- function(x) `diag<-`(outer(x, x, Vectorize(helper)), "")

or its variant but a bit faster
f2 <- function(x) {
    res <- matrix(rep("", length(x)^2), length(x))
    v <- combn(x, 2, \(p) helper(p[1], p[2]))
    res[lower.tri(res)] <- v
    res[upper.tri(res)] <- t(res)[upper.tri(res)]
    res
}

such that
> f1(x)
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3] [,4]
[1,] ""      "01001" "01" "010"
[2,] "01001" ""      "01" "010"
[3,] "01"    "01"    ""   "01"
[4,] "010"   "010"   "01" ""

> f2(x)
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3] [,4]
[1,] ""      "01001" "01" "010"
[2,] "01001" ""      "01" "010"
[3,] "01"    "01"    ""   "01"
[4,] "010"   "010"   "01" ""

Benchmark
set.seed(0)
x <- replicate(1000, paste0(sample.int(2, sample(5, 1), TRUE) - 1, collapse = ""))
microbenchmark(
    f1(x),
    f2(x),
    unit = "relative",
    times = 10L,
    check = "equal"
)

shows
Unit: relative
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f1(x) 2.125062 2.010759 2.057626 1.951325 2.154321 2.099333    10
 f2(x) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10


@ZéLoff Thanks! Yes, you are right, that would be faster if using which.max

@ThomasIsCoding Thank you for your nice answer! There seems to be a bug though. If I run helper("1","11") I get "" rather than "1"

@SamR Thanks you for pointing it out. I added it into the code now.

@mto_19 sorry for the bug. I tweaked a little bit and hope it is bug-free now

@ThomasIsCoding Thank you for the modification. Yes, it works now as expected.

Using data.table for some costly steps can scale per thread. Only printing the upper triangle.
library(data.table) # rleid, tstrsplit

getPsub <- function(dat){

  len <- seq_along(dat)
  mlen <- max(len)

  mat <- matrix(NA, mlen, mlen)
  d <- do.call(rbind, tstrsplit(dat, ""))

  mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- apply(combn(len, 2), 2, \(x){
    res <- d[,x[1]] == d[,x[2]]
    paste(d[rleid(res) == 1 & res, x[1]], collapse="")})

  t(mat)
}

output
getPsub(x)
     [,1] [,2]    [,3] [,4]
[1,] NA   "01001" "01" "010"
[2,] NA   NA      "01" "010"
[3,] NA   NA      NA   "01"
[4,] NA   NA      NA   NA

